# Single handler for 9 buttons (gtkmm-2, libsigc++)

Tags: gtk, signals, gtkmm, libsigc++

I'm trying to make a **widget with 9 toggle-buttons** (3 rows and 3 columns), the user shall be able to select one of those. So i wrote **9 event handlers**, which disabled the currently selected button and store the selection.

I just wanted to know if there is any way to **connect those 9 toggle buttons** to one single handler, and if there is a way to **know which button emitted the signal**. Something similar to QT's

```
QObject::sender()
```

This would avoid a lot of repetition in my code. As noted in the title I am using gtkmm version 2 and of course sigc++.

Thank you in advice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used c++11 lambdas to solve a similar problem.  Basically you capture the information about the target in the lambda so when the signal fires you can do something target specific. For example:

```
abutton.signal_clicked().connect([this,&abutton]{ handle_click(abutton); });
```

I believe this will work with gtkmm 2.x, but I have only used it with 3.0 and I don't know how sigc++ has changed between the two versions.  If you can't use c++11 features, you might be able to do something similar with the lambda functionality that comes with sigc++, but I've no experience with it.

Comment: Another way is given by @Ivarpoiss 's comment to ptomato's answer, and also my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13613054/240633

Answer (score 2):

I'm not that familiar with gtkmm, but in plain C GTK, the signal handler looks like this:

```
void on_button_toggled (GtkToggleButton *button, gpointer user_data);
```

The `button` pointer is the 'sender' in QT terminology. To find out which button is which, you could name them, or attach data with `g_object_set_data()`.

Comment: button->signal_clicked().connect(sigc::bind<Gtk::Button&>(sigc::mem_fun(*this, &MyWidget::on_button_clicked), *button)); in Gtkmm